# Does Turkey have an extradition treaty with Saudi Arabia?

Tags: international, turkey, saudi-arabia

Jamal Khashoggi's murder happened in the Saudi Arabia embassy in Turkey.  President Erdogan wants the 15 men suspects to be tried in Turkey.  Is that possible?

Comment: I would not hold my breath.  This appears to be saber rattling.  The first step that Erdogan would take if he meant it would be to recall diplomats and expel the Saudi mission. If that has not happened yet, it is so much hot air

Comment: Highly unlikely , supposed murder happened in Saudi consulate, i.e. on Saudi territory. No Turkish citizen was involved, therefore Turkey has no grounds to call for extradition.

Comment: Very unlikely, if the suspects even get held accountable, the murder was committed in the Saudi Consulate, which is Saudi territory.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/32864

Answer (score 4):

Saudi Arabia and Turkey have no extradition treaty ([Source](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/jamal-khashoggi-death-international-law-prosecute-istanbul-saudi-arabia-mohammed-bin-salman-a8596236.html)). It's possible, however very unlikely, that an ad hoc arrangement could be made between the two parties for only this case. Recently, such an agreement was used to extradite people accused of war crimes from the UK to Rwanda.

Comment: I think also there was recently some similar ad hoc arrangement done between the US and Taiwan (I think, might be mis-remembering) with regards to the defense distributed guy.

Comment: Would a treaty be needed? Surely Turkey has the right to _ask_ for extradition. Without a treaty, Saudi Arabia has the right to refuse, but I would assume they also have the right to extradite someone. And currently it looks like they might be willing to do that.

Answer (score 3):

There is one agreement (31/05/1930) listed in the [judicial agreements](http://www.uhdigm.adalet.gov.tr/sozlesmeler/ikili.html) (only available in Turkish), however it doesn't state anything about extradition.

On the other hand, [Turkish sources](https://www.haberturk.com/turkiye-389-kisinin-iadesini-istedi-1870353) report that Saudi Arabia extradited 4 suspects in 2017.

> Almanya ve Gürcistan’dan 12’şer isim, Türkiye’nin talebi
>   üzerine iade edildi. Almanya ve Gürcistan’ı 5 suçlu iadesiyle
>   Azerbaycan, **4**’er iadeyle ise Bulgaristan, KKTC, **Suudi Arabistan** ve
>   Ukrayna izledi.